# Arduino Geiger Counter

Tags: arduino, transistors, capacitor, circuit-analysis, geiger-muller-tube

I have found somewhere the following scheme for an arduino based geiger counter. (The arduino main purpose is to count the pulses from the tube) As far as I can understand it, the transistor would amplify the small current coming from the tube and the arduino would then detect a low logic level when a ionizing radiation is passing. My doubt is about the capacitor: why is it there? I have tried to build the circuit simulating the passage of radiation by pressing a button. I tried to remove the cap from the circuit too, and yet the detection is noticeably more accurate with the capacitor in. I guess it is because the capacitor is like a filter for "false pulses".Can someone please explain me the role C1?
[image]

Comment: I would guess the capacitor lengthens the low pulse because it has to charge back up after each pulse.

Comment: if you want to sumulate radiation by pressing a button connect a full size microswitch with NO connected to C and NC  connected to A, leave Common unconnected.

Answer (score 1):

It's there to stretch the pulses into something the arduino can see.

AVR microcontrollers can't reliably detect pulses shorter than one clock period.

the capscitor in combination with the pull-up resistor will stetch the pulses out to ballpark 100 microseconds which should be easily detectable.

Answer (score 0):

C1 acts as an integrator. The current out of the geiger tube is amplified by Q1, then the collector current is integrated on C1. The current is a pretty sharp pulse of short duration so it will look like a voltage step. The voltage step then exponentially decays back up to the baseline (~5V) with the time constant C1*Rpullup (~103 ns).

Answer (score -1):

The capacitor works as an output voltage stabilizer: a random short "firing" of the transistor doesn't discharge the capacitor much, and hence doesn't register as pulse.

Comment: Why do you call it "voltage stabilizer" if the effect you describe usually called "filter". Or low-pass filter, to be precise. I understand that the two could be the same in some context, but somehow this does not feel to be the case.

Comment: Well, it's a filter, but but very much in the sense you'd usually use it. You could call it a noise suppressor; it builds a pulse energy threshold in conjunction with the gpio voltage threshold. There's many names you can call it by

Comment: what a wonderfully non-linear circuit

Comment: well yeah, GM tubes have negative resistance. the circuits fine if you want to count individual events.  it;s not designed to drive a pointer.